# ¿Seria on-topic una pregunta sobre la traducción de un juego de palabras en particular?

Tags: discusión, ámbito, off-topic

Hace como un mes quise hacer una pregunta, pero me faltó tiempo para publicarla y luego empecé a preguntarme si sería on-topic o no, así que hoy he sacado tiempo para preguntar en meta.

El contexto de la pregunta es que mi hijo mayor esta ahora *flipao* con ballenas, delfines, tiburones y similares animales marinos. En su clase de preescolar conocen su obsesión (que ha contagiado a casi todos) y este año al empezar las clases (repite con el mismo grupo de profesores por segundo año) la profesora hizo un cartel que ponía

> Whale-come to preschool

Evidentemente, es un juego de palabras entre "welcome" (bienvenidos) y "whale" (ballena).

La cosa habría quedado ahí si no fuera porque, como expatriados que somos, solemos mandar un correo mensual a familiares y amigos con algunas de nuestras aventures y desventuras, y esta anécdota por supuesto se coló en el correo de septiembre.

Mandamos el correo en español e inglés. Muchos de nuestros familiares y amigos no hablan inglés y me pregunté en su momento tanto si era posible traducir ese juego de palabras en lugar de explicarlo y cómo se podría hacer.

Huelga decir que me pilló el toro para traducir el juego de palabras en el correo de septiembre. Como a mi no se me ocurría nada, pensé en preguntar por aquí, pero al poco me asaltaron las dudas sobre si la pregunta sería on-topic.

Por un lado, se podría argumentar que las posibles distintas traducciones (de haberlas) serían todas igualmente válidas como respuesta, y elegir una respuesta aceptada sería una mera elección personal. La pregunta sería por tanto off-topic.

Por otro lado, podría entenderse que la pregunta se presta a tener múltiples respuestas, de las que se puede juzgar el mérito (lo bien que se aproximen al original, que conserven la sonoridad, etc.) y se podría elegir una mejor respuesta en base a criterios objetivos (incluso para la traducción de un juego de palabras).

A mí se me podría convencer fácilmente de cualquiera de las dos cosas, y le he dado tantas vueltas que empiezo a perder la claridad. Para más inri, existe la posibilidad de que a nadie se le ocurra una traducción, con lo que no sabríamos bien si no es posible traducir ese juego de palabras o si es que no se nos ocurre nada.

Para clarificar, no estoy preguntado si las preguntas sobre traducción de juegos de palabras en general son on-topic/off-topic, aunque podríamos encarrilar hacia ahí esta discusión.

Entiendo que es necesario considerar el caso particular de esta, pero se puede expandir la pregunta par hacerla más general si vemos que con eso aprendemos un poco más sobre los límites del sitio.

Así que, discusión: ¿Es la pregunta propuesta sobre la traducción de este juego de palabras on-topic u off-topic?

> Whale-come to preschool

Answer (score 2):

If we think about the situation where a question has several answers then how do we choose which to vote for, or which to accept? Surely we do this based on some internal set of criteria about what makes a good answer. So I do not see the situation here as being fundamentally different from many other questions. I would say it is on-topic.

Comment: Agreed, to me it is perfectly on topic also